# SubSonic3: Method "FirstOrDefault" throws exception with SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, sql-server-2000, subsonic3

I am using SubSonic3 with SQL Server 2000.

I have problem with the method "FirstOrDefault" - it always throws an exception = "Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('." from the SubSonic.Linq dll

EDIT (Added code from comment):

```
InventoryDAL = DAL project name (dll) 
Inventort= Subsonic3 Gnerated classes 
Name space WHWarehouses = gnerated object 

Dim WareH = (From Wh In InventoryDAL.Inventort.WHWarehouses.All _ 
  Where Wh.WarehouseID = 1 ).FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: can you use SQL Profiler to see what's executing on Sql server?

Comment: If you could please add some code to show what you are doing exactly and we would be much better able to help you.

Comment: yes - definitely - show us your code snippet that makes this call!

Comment: InventoryDAL = DAL project name (dll)
Inventort= Subsonic3 Gnerated classes Name space
WHWarehouses = gnerated object

Dim WareH = (From Wh In InventoryDAL.Inventort.WHWarehouses.All _
             Where Wh.WarehouseID = 1 ).FirstOrDefault

Comment: dont you need to close FirstOrDefault like FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SubSonic, but Hibernate has different dialects of SQL you can tell it to use, might want to see if there is any way to tell it to use a dialect for SQL 2000

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I've encountered too and unfortunately the code to generate the TOP is generated in the SubSonic Dependency and cannot be changed in the TT templates.

In the SubSonic source under **TSqlFormatter**.cs class is a method

```
protected override Expression VisitSelect(SelectExpression select)
```

...

```
if (select.Take != null)
            {
                sb.Append("TOP (");
                this.Visit(select.Take);
                sb.Append(") ");
            }
```

....

Removing the brackets in db.Append should fix the issue for SQL but I'm not sure whether this may break other providers such as SQL Compact Edition?

I raised it here: [SubSonic Bug with TOP keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447372/subsonic-bug-with-top-keyword) before I read you query.

Hope this helps.